# I want to write only jsp, jstl in .jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I'm learning JSTl+EL and I don't like that I have to use `<% %>` tags inside of `JSP` files. I also haven't found good documentation on the topic as well - good pointers welcomed. (This: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/ isn't helping much). So my question is can I write some better JSTL+EL below so that i could get `<% %>` tags out of my JSP? :)

```
<% if (session.getAttribute("error") != null) {%>
            <jsp:useBean id="error" class="java.lang.String" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
            <%=error %>     
            <%}else if(session.getAttribute("searchData")!= null){%>
            <%=session.getAttribute("searchData")!=null %>
            <jsp:include page="session_object_ok.jsp"></jsp:include>            
            <%}%>
            <%
                session.setAttribute("searchData", null);
            %>
```

Comment: If you click the tags you've added, they will bring you to that tag's page. There is a tab on the left called `info`. Go there and read some of the tutorials and questions.

Comment: `<% %>` these are called scriptlets by the way and not tags. You really need to read Stackoverflow tags wiki for [tag:jsp], [tag:el] and [tag:jstl]. And to answer your question "Yes you can write better JSTL and EL". Follow the tag wiki.

Comment: Thanks, already on it, and helpful thanks.

Comment: many good tutorials on this site: http://www.coreservlets.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
<% if (session.getAttribute("error") != null) {%>
```

can be translated to

```html
<c:if test="${error != null}">
```

or if you'd like to cover empty string as well

```html
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
```

An alternative is `<c:choose><c:when>`.

---

This

```html
<jsp:useBean id="error" class="java.lang.String" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
```

is completely unnecessary if you've already done `session.setAttribute("error", error)` in a servlet beforehand. Just get rid of it altogether.

---

This

```
<%=error %>
```

can be translated to

```
${error}
```

or if you'd like to prevent XSS attack holes if it contains user-controlled data (such as request parameters)

```html
<c:out value="${error}" />
```

Note that it already prints *nothing* if it's null or empty. So the whole `<c:if>` around it is basically superfluous.

---

This,

```
<%}else if(session.getAttribute("searchData")!= null){%>
```

can be translated to

```html
<c:if test="${searchData != null}">
```

Or just `${not empty searchData}`. An alternative is `<c:otherwise>` in the same `<c:choose>`.

---

This

```
<% session.setAttribute("searchData", null); %>
```

can be translated to

```
<c:remove scope="session" var="searchData" />
```

However, if it's always been set in the *current* request, then this isn't making any sense. Just set it as a request attribtue in first place by `request.setAttribute("searchData", searchData)` in a servlet beforehand.

---

All in all, provided that your servlet look like this:

```
try {
    SearchData searchData = searchService.find(query);
    request.setAttribute("searchData", searchData);
} catch (SomeException e) {
    request.setAttribute("error", "Sorry, search failed. Please try again.");
}

request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/searchResult.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

then this should do:

```html
${error}
<c:if test="${not empty searchData}">
    <jsp:include page="session_object_ok.jsp" />
</c:if>
```

Your JSP include page has by the way a quite strange filename.

---

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: WOOP! How beautiful my code looks now BIG THANKS! =) you have few typos at the beginning you wrote # instead of $, i can't fix them :)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, the `#{}` syntax is from JSP's successor [Facelets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info) which I use daily instead of legacy JSP. It just slipped through.

Answer (score 0):

something as simple as this, a simple google search over jstl core tag will let you do something like this:

```
<c:set var="yourError" value="${error}" scope="session"/>
<c:choose> 
    <c:when test="${not empty yourError}">
        <c:out value="$(yourError}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${searchData}">
        <jsp:include page="session_object_ok.jsp"/>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
<c:set var="searchData" value="null"/>
```

Comment: Well i can't write `""` around `error`, nor does it understand it with out them. Same with `searchData`.

Comment: And from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/ i cant set `scope` property to `when`

Comment: fixed, the scope property, took it out into a different var... don't get what you mean by can't write "" around error...

Comment: If i use `scope` in `out` i get this error:`Attribute scope invalid for tag out according to TLD
` if i take `scope` away i get `$(yourError}` printed

Comment: yes you're right, I just passed changing it when modified it... hope this have helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a book that could help you. See [*JSTL in Action*](http://www.manning.com/bayern/) by Shawn Bayern.

See also the ['jstl' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)  from Stack Overflow